# Is there a special name or any research on Cartesian compact closed categories?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

As per the title. I can't find anything about the combination of the two, and such categories interest me. Does anyone know of any such categories?

Comment: Bob Coecke mentions something like this here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07618 (section 4.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only dualisable object in a cartesian monoidal category is the terminal object. Thus, a cartesian compact closed category must be trivial.

Indeed, suppose $A$ has a dual $A^*$. Since the unit object is terminal, the counit $\epsilon : A \times A^* \to 1$ is forced. Consider the unit $\eta : 1 \to A^* \times A$. This decomposes into components as a morphism $1 \to A^*$ and a morphism $1 \to A$. By definition, $(\epsilon \times \mathrm{id}_A) \circ (\mathrm{id}_A \times \eta) = \mathrm{id}_A$; but $\epsilon \times \mathrm{id}_A : A \times A^* \times A \to A$ is the third projection, so the condition means that $A \to 1 \to A$ is $\mathrm{id}_A$. On the other hand, $1 \to A \to 1$ must be $\mathrm{id}_1$, so we deduce $A \cong 1$.

Comment: Here is an alternative proof, which even works in arbitrary monoidal categories in which $1$ is terminal: Assume that $A^*$ is a dual of $A$, i.e. $\hom(X \otimes A,Y) \cong \hom(X,Y \otimes A^*)$, natural in $X,Y$. For $Y=1$ we see that $\hom(X,A^*)=1$ i.e. $A^* \cong 1$. Hence, $X \otimes A \cong X$, in particular $A \cong 1$.

Comment: Hmm, damn. Is there a way to have "products" (or something like them) in a compact closed category?

Comment: The category of finite dimensional vector spaces is a compact closed category and has finite products.